# Most efficient way to turn dictionary into symmetric/distance matrix in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, distance

I'm doing pairwise distance for something with a weird distance metric.  I have a dictionary like `{(key_A, key_B):distance_value}` and I want to make a symmetric `pd.DataFrame` like a distance matrix.

What is the most efficient way to do this? I found one way but it doesn't seem like the best way to do this. Is there anything in `NumPy` or `Pandas` that does this type of operation? or just a quicker way? My way is `1.46 ms per loop`

```
np.random.seed(0)
D_pair_value = dict()
for pair in itertools.combinations(list("ABCD"),2):
    D_pair_value[pair] = np.random.randint(0,5)
D_pair_value
# {('A', 'B'): 4,
#  ('A', 'C'): 0,
#  ('A', 'D'): 3,
#  ('B', 'C'): 3,
#  ('B', 'D'): 3,
#  ('C', 'D'): 1}
D_nested_dict = defaultdict(dict)
for (p,q), value in D_pair_value.items():
    D_nested_dict[p][q] = value
    D_nested_dict[q][p] = value

# Fill diagonal with zeros
DF = pd.DataFrame(D_nested_dict)
np.fill_diagonal(DF.values, 0)
DF
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html#scipy.spatial.distance.squareform), which converts a vector of distance computations, i.e. `[d(A,B), d(A,C), ..., d(C,D)]`, into the distance matrix you're looking for.

**Method 1: Distances Stored in a List**

If you're computing your distances in order, like in your example code and in my example distance vector, I'd avoid using a dictionary and just store the results in a list, and do something like:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

df = pd.DataFrame(squareform(dist_list), index=list('ABCD'), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

**Method 2: Distances Stored in a Dictionary**

If you're computing things out of order and a dictionary is required, you just need to get a distance vector that's properly sorted:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

dist_list = [dist[1] for dist in sorted(D_pair_value.items())]
df = pd.DataFrame(squareform(dist_list), index=list('ABCD'), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

**Method 3: Distances Stored in a Sorted Dictionary**

If a dictionary is required, note that there's a package called [`sortedcontainers`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sortedcontainers) which has a [`SortedDict`](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html) that essentially would solve the sorting issue for you.  To use it, all you'd need to change is initializing `D_pair_value` as a `SortedDict()` instead of a `dict`.  Using your example setup:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform
from sortedcontainers import SortedDict

np.random.seed(0)
D_pair_value = SortedDict()
for pair in itertools.combinations(list("ABCD"),2):
    D_pair_value[pair] = np.random.randint(0,5)

df = pd.DataFrame(squareform(D_pair_value.values()), index=list('ABCD'), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

**The Resulting Output for Any Method Above:**

```
     A    B    C    D
A  0.0  4.0  0.0  3.0
B  4.0  0.0  3.0  3.0
C  0.0  3.0  0.0  1.0
D  3.0  3.0  1.0  0.0
```

Comment: Thank you! I've learned something new today: `scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`

Comment: A great solution here. Thanks, @MaxU

Answer (score 2):

Given a dictionary of keys (of single characters) and distances, here's a NumPy based approach -

```
def dict2frame(D_pair_value):
    # Extract keys and values
    k = np.array(D_pair_value.keys())
    v = np.array(D_pair_value.values())

    # Get row, col indices from keys
    idx = (np.fromstring(k.tobytes(),dtype=np.uint8)-65).reshape(-1,2)

    # Setup output array and using row,col indices set values from v
    N = idx.max()+1
    out = np.zeros((N,N),dtype=v.dtype)
    out[idx[:,0],idx[:,1]] = v
    out[idx[:,1],idx[:,0]] = v

    header = list("".join([chr(item) for item in np.arange(N)+65]))
    return pd.DataFrame(out,index=header, columns=header)
```

Sample run -

```
In [166]: D_pair_value
Out[166]: 
{('A', 'B'): 4,
 ('A', 'C'): 0,
 ('A', 'D'): 3,
 ('B', 'C'): 3,
 ('B', 'D'): 3,
 ('C', 'D'): 1}

In [167]: dict2frame(D_pair_value)
Out[167]: 
   A  B  C  D
A  0  4  0  3
B  4  0  3  3
C  0  3  0  1
D  3  3  1  0
```